# It runs in VS2012 but hides the form's GUI at design-time; in Visual C# Express 2010 it doesn't even compile

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

Since the xaml window stopped showing my wpf form using VS 2012 (after I added some comments to the top of the main .cs form), I reverted back to C# Express 2010.

I copied my xaml and code and pasted them into the new project.

However, I'm getting err msgs such as:

*'duckbilledPlatypusInfoMailer_Express.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'MainWindow_Loaded' and no extension method 'MainWindow_Loaded' accepting a first argument of type 'duckbilledPlatypusInfoMailer_Express.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

and:

*The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context*

I get the same err msg about two controls, my label and button (but not the DatePicker!)

So both of my event handlers, and two of my three controls, as well as the 'InitializeComponent' have been rendered in a cloak of invisibility, as far as VC#2010 is concerned...???

Here is my xaml and code (minimal, so p[a,o]sting all of it):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="duckbilledPlatypusInfoMailer_Express.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Duckbilled Platypus Info Mailer"  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MinHeight="350" MinWidth="525" Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded" >
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btnSelectPDFFile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="4" Margin="4" Width="120" Click="btnSelectPDFFile_Click" IsDefault="True">Select PDF File
            </Button>
            <Label x:Name="lblPlatypusSheetFile" Margin="4" >[Selected File]</Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <DatePicker ></DatePicker>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using duckbilledPlatypusInfoMailer;

namespace PlatypusInfo_Express
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnSelectPDFFile.Focus();
        }

        private void btnSelectPDFFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                        var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
                          {
                              InitialDirectory = @"C:\Scrooge\McDuckbilledPlatypus\",
                              DefaultExt = ".pdf",
                              Filter = "Platypus Data Sheets (sa*.pdf)|sa*.pdf"
                          };

            bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                string pdfFilename = dlg.FileName;
                // Show just the file name, without the path
                string pdfFileNameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfFilename);
                lblReviewSheetFile.Content = pdfFileNameOnly;
                string textFilename = String.Format(@"C:\Scrooge\McDuckbilledPlatypus\{0}.txt", pdfFileNameOnly);
                var pdfParser = new PDFParser();
                if (pdfParser.ExtractText(pdfFilename, textFilename))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(textFilename);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There was a boo-boo, Yogi!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, I did add the necessary 3rd party file to my solution (PDFParser.cs) as well as the two necessary references.

Note: If I right-click the event handlers in the xaml, it DOES take me to those event handlers in the cs file. So it knows where they are, why does it say they don't exist or it can't find them?

### UPDATE

Here's the first part of the error I see in the WPF designer:

System.NotSupportedException
An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func)

Comment: Did you solve this ? I have been having this pb with 3 different machines over the last year....

Comment: No, I just (temporarily) abandoned it/moved on.

Comment: I think I found the answer on another thread. not only do you have to touch the devenv.exe.config for remoteresources, but there are 2 other config files. I'll post it here tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra `duckbilled` in the namespace in the XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="duckbilledPlatypusInfoMailer_Express.MainWindow"
```

it has to be in the same namespace as to code behind class.

Comment: Thanks; that's not the actual namespace, as I suppose you sussed, but I somehow did have a superfluous "s" in the xaml file. Now I'm going to go back to VS2012 and see if that "s" snuck in there somehow, too. Dang fat fingers!

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with VS2012, the error message is clearly when the XAML and code behind don't have the same namespace.

Comment: In VS2012 the error messages are different, and the namespaces are the same, yet it still doesn't work. The only thing that had changed between working and not working was when I added some comments to the top of the .cs file.

Comment: I'm adding the first part of the err msg above. They claimed that if I right-clicked the 3rd party assembly in the References folder, I would see an "Unblock" item at the bottom; click on that, and I would be transported to the Big Rock Candy Mountain. However, I don't even see an "Unblock" checkbox...

Comment: I removed the assemblies Microsoft claimed was the problem, and the designer is still hosed, so I think they were wrong (besides, it works fine in Visual C# Express)